# XSLT to nest one schema within another

Tags: xslt, metadata

I use an XSLT crosswalk to transform our standard in-house metadata XML to PBCore.
My prologue at the top of the xslt looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="2.0">  
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="MediaAsset">
    <pbcoreCollection 
        xmlns="http://www.pbcore.org/PBCore/PBCoreNamespace.html"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.pbcore.org/PBCore/PBCoreNamespace.html 
http://pbcore.org/xsd/pbcore-2.0.xsd">
```

Now I have a client asking for our PBCore metadata to be added to their own MODS metadata that they provide to us. I know that to properly next our PBCore within their MODS, all my tags have to have a pbcore: prefix. So my question is: how do I adapt my PBCore XSLT that I run our standard XML through to include the prefix in the output file? If I can do that then I can just copy the PBCore metadata and paste it into their MODs metadata, and just add

```
xmlns:pbcore="http://www.pbcore.org/PBCore/PBCoreNamespace.html"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3 
http://www.loc.gov/standards/mods/v3/mods-3-6.xsd
http://www.pbcore.org/PBCore/PBCoreNamespace.html 
http://pbcore.org/xsd/pbcore-2.0.xsd">
```

to the prologue of the final output XML.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than modifying your existing XSLT code, why not add another step to the pipeline that modifies the output of the existing stylesheet to meet the new requirements?

It's not entirely clear to me what the new requirements are. You talk about namespace prefixes needing to be changed, but generally speaking, namespace prefixes are purely cosmetic: it's namespace URIs that matter.